# psexec how to start .bat file on multiply machines

Tags: windows-7, psexec

How to set up list of machines in text file?
Is it possible to run .bat file  on multiply machines ? 
I have at least 90 computers and .bat file in the same path on each machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
psexec.exe \\COMPUTER C:\script.bat
```

To run against all computers in the current domain, replace  \\COMPUTER with "\\*"

Comment: Is it possible to acces to specyfic computers ?

Comment: By Ip adres or DNS name ?

Comment: I created text file with the name of serwer (\\ip addres) and i tried to execute psexec with this command "PsExec serverlist.txt cmd", but i got this error "%1 is not a valid Win32 application." But when i tried to execute this without txt file it will work. Still i prefer execute this from txt file if i have more then 1 PC

Comment: @Wiktor Kostrzewski have you try `psexec @c:\computers.txt`

Comment: I changed solution a bit, and  i created a batch  - for /f %%a  in (C:\list.txt) do psexec -u doman\username -p password \\%%a cmd /c C:\WMS4\start.bat and now i got a new error" Could not start PSEXESVC service on 10.17.12.59:
Access is denied."

Comment: @Wiktor Kostrzewski Like this: `-u [domain]\username -p password`.

Comment: for /f %%a  in (C:\Users\kostrzew\Desktop\PSTools\list.txt) do psexec -u [domain]\user -p password \\%%a cmd /c C:\WMS4\start.bat

Comment: this is a start.bat  - "c:\python26\python update.py
@if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 ProcessConfigurator.exe
pause "

Comment: When you pass -u -p,the user must have right to run the command.

Comment: If you specify `-u [domain]\username -p password` as first arguments it should work.